# how to create a table with two columns and 12 rows in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments

I should create a table as shown in the link below, I thought of implementing this in two ways.

1. I should create a table with borders in static way and update the contents dynamically, I mean static months in first column and dynamic values in second column using activity.
2. I can dynamically set both columns by supplying month name and values from activity.

My questions are:

1. How to create this table with white background and borders as shown below ? Since I couldn't spot any blog with a table containing white background and borders.
2. How to supply dynamic values to each cell of the table from the activity.

[image: table image]

Comment: pls show some code to dynamically update the row. besides pls see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:--

### my_drawable.xml(Used for border):-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#B8B9B1" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="3px"
    android:left="3px"
    android:right="3px"
    android:top="3px">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

### xml:--

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Months" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Number of Visits" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="January" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Februrary" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I have just added 3 rows now.I just show you how to do it.
And for white border and all that you need to create Layer-list drawable and set it to your tablelayout.
Enjoy..!

Comment: Kailash Dabhi, Setting the borders with solid color and textview with white color as i stated above is the big issue for me. For color background your post is good to know.

Comment: so you want exactly the same way as image?

Comment: Yeah but the table which i stated should be resizeable,i mean it should not occupy the full screen.

Comment: this exactly solved my issue

Comment: thanks Kailash Dabhi :)

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do that...
The best I can think of is using a ListView.
Then add a border to it by using a 9 patch.
Another 9 patch can be used by its (custom) row elements (two textviews, actually).

Here you are the required 9 patches for external and internal borders:

[image] (external - table borders)

[image] (internal - cell borders)

Save these images in your res/drawable folder, with the extension **.9.png**
Then add them as your android:background attribute.

For how to make a custom ListView, search on Google - there's a plenty of examples.

Comment: I am new to android, I can't get you what you speak !! I know how to create listview but i don't know anything about 9 patch

Comment: It's a very conenient way to provide stretchable images. I can provide you those, if you want me to.

Comment: ya thanks can you post some demo.

Comment: I will try to solve with Kailash Dabhi answer if that doesn't work for me then as you said i will do as you said. thanks :)

Comment: Yes, but it's a waste of Layouts... which will resul in a heavier combo. That's why i said that the best way I could think of was a very lightweight ListView control.

Answer (score 0):

Like Klaus66 said there are many ways to do it.

When i had a similar case, i created corresponding table layout in xml, and now the tricky part(since you dont have table borders like in CSS) you can create table cells with background and borders using pure xml styling and drawables.

Try google-ing for list-layers, here is an example i used:(table cell with bottom and left border 1dp width)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item> 
 <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#004536" /> 
  </shape>
  </item>   
   <item android:left="1dp" android:bottom="1dp"  > 
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#25272f" /> 
     </shape> 
  </item>    
 </layer-list>
```

And just set this drawable as background for your table cell.(your textView-s in your rows,columns...).

Edit 1: As for supplying values to your cells, in your activity use findViewById(R.id...) to get your textViews you used in your layout an place values you like.

Comment: for color background i found some similar example like you posted above, but for white background with solid borders it's difficult to set.

Comment: What causes the problem? White is a color also :) it should not matter what color you use for background(white->#ffffff) just be carefull not to use transparent.

Comment: JanBo as you mentioned for white #ffffff is okay for white background but what for that solid border, I can't use other colors for that.

Comment: Using this layer list, you chose different colors for border and background?

Comment: Unless you want to have a white background, and white borders like in your picture, just with those gray shadows then maybe the best thing is to use 9patch, it will be easier for you.

Comment: okay I will try to use any one of these solutions !!!